# Capping a sub-expression in numexpr

Tags: python, numpy, pytables, numexpr

How do I efficiently express the following using [`numexpr`](http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/)?

```
z = min(x-y, 1.0) / (x+y)
```

Here, `x` and `y` are some large NumPy arrays of the same shape.

In other words, I am trying to cap `x-y` to `1.0` before dividing it by `x+y`.

I would like to do this using a single `numexpr` expression (`x` and `y` are huge, and I don't want to have to iterate over them more than once).

Comment: Just to be clear (because min(x-y, 1) isn't valid numpy), do you want to cap x-y to an upper bound of 1 before dividing by (x+y)?

Comment: @DSM: Yes, this is precisely what I am trying to do. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work?

```
In [11]: import numpy as np
In [12]: import numexpr as ne    
In [13]:     
In [13]: x = np.linspace(0.02, 5.0, 1e7)
In [14]: y = np.sin(x)
In [15]:     
In [15]: timeit z0 = ((x-y) - ((x-y) > 1) * (x-y - 1))/(x+y)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.02 s per loop
In [16]: timeit z1 = ne.evaluate("((x-y) - ((x-y) > 1.) * ((x-y) - 1.))/(x+y)")
10 loops, best of 3: 120 ms per loop    
In [17]: timeit z2 = ne.evaluate("((x-y)/(x+y))")
10 loops, best of 3: 103 ms per loop
```

There's a penalty for the capping above the division, but it's not too bad.  Unfortunately when I tried it for some larger arrays it segfaulted. :-/

Update: this is much prettier, and a little faster too:

```
In [40]: timeit w0 = ne.evaluate("where(x-y>1,1,x-y)/(x+y)")
10 loops, best of 3: 114 ms per loop
```